# Why does the Republic in the prequels use the iconography and general imagery of the Sith Empire from the Cold War days?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I understand Bioware's desire to represent the old Sith Empire similar to the Empire of Episodes IV to VI, but has there been any in-universe reason why the Republic would eventually come to adopt the iconography and general imagery of their nemesis?

Comment: Can you provide some examples? I don't recall noticing this anywhere, but depending on *what* the icons in question are it may be a construct of Galactic Basic (which, as the name implies, is the common language spoken throughout the galaxy) or a generic icon that (almost) everyone uses, regardless of origin (similar to, for example, the [Power Icon](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/u/i/J/X/2/p/power-icon-md.png) that you'll find almost everywhere here on Planet Earth, regardless of nation, culture, language, etc.).

Comment: Nazi swastica was a buddhist symbol before that. Red Cross uses the same symbol as crusaders who sacked cities. Reuse of symbols and icons is common in even Earth history

Comment: The Red Cross is a great example then, much akin to something like this, why did they do that? EDIT: Examples; General design of star destroyers/ the "bendu-inspired logo of the republic(used after the Cold War) that looks much like the Sith Empire's(which they had fought) logo. Wookiepedia has no information that I can find on why this would be, in fact they don't even include the logo of the Sith Empire during the Cold War.

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSAEcWiSfq6BzYtw-JcTaY-1AMxyzRac3JiAs4se7NWApf1OE9k_w     Here is a link to the Cold War Sith/Republic Logos, and the Republic logo during the prequels.

Comment: This could be a case of Palpatine using his influence to get this logo in as a private joke or honor to his Sith affiliation, but nobody else really makes the connection given how long ago the Cold War was.

Answer (score 12):

The symbol/iconography you're referring to is known across the galaxy as the "Bendu Wheel". The [Bendu Order](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_Dai_Bendu) of monks is ancient, pre-dating the Old Republic by at least 10,000 years. Similar to the Buddhists of our world, the Bendu undertake a philosophy of passive restraint and unification through peace & dialogue. The wheel - an unbroken circle in which the center "reaches out" to the edges - is the Bendu symbol for unification. As you can see in the graphic below, several variations of this symbol have been used by those who seek to unify the galaxy:

[image]

It should be noted that these symbols are not necessarily based on each other, but on the concept behind the symbol. The Old Republic had based its logo on the Bendu Wheel as early as 5000 years BBY, but later exchanged it for a bird motif.

When the Second Sith Empire attempted to conquer the galaxy, they used an angular variation of the wheel with six spokes as their icon - most likely hoping to convey the idea they were uniting the galaxy under a single banner rather than conquering it.

Centuries after the war, the Republic again embraced the Bendu wheel as its own symbol, depicting it instead with the original eight spokes. The Republic wanted to convey that they were a single government uniting all the disparate worlds & cultures of the galaxy.

When Palpatine later declared himself Emperor and changed the Galactic Republic of Worlds into the Galactic Empire, he updated the icon to more closely represent that previously used by the Sith. The resulting symbol can be seen, appropriately, as a merger of the Sith and Republic icons.