# What is the Galactic Republic logo supposed to represent?

Tags: star-wars

I originally wanted to ask about the Galactic Empire logo, but then I noticed it looked like basically an inverted logo of the Galactic Republic, its predecessor. The logical question then becomes the origin of THAT logo.

[image]

What is the origin of the above Galactic Republic logo?

Comment: I assumed it was a crude representation of the Star Wars Galaxy; http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/1/10/MainGalaxy.png/revision/latest?cb=20130325041255 With the core worlds at the centre, hyperspace corridors and the outer rim.

Comment: Highly related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58443/31936

Comment: Great find..pretty close to a dupe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Legends, it originated from **Bendu**

From the [**Wikia**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bendu)

> Bendu was a collection of non-confrontational beliefs practiced by the Bendu monks. The symbol of Bendu was a circle connected by eight even spokes, which represented the unification of the galaxy by the Force. **Due to their study of numerology, the number eight created by this symbol had great meaning.**

*Sith Empire*

> Symbol used by the Sith Empire during the Galactic War

[image]

*Bendu (reduced)*

> Reduced form of the Bendu symbol used on Anakin Skywalker's ship during the Clone Wars

[image]

*Palpatine*

> Palpatine's Bendu inspired Imperial crest

[image]

> Even though the symbol of the Bendu was eventually used by the Galactic Republic, they at first used their own symbol [Not given]. Curiously, the later reformed Sith Empire used a six-spoked symbol similar to the one used by the Republic after the Second Sith Civil War. By then, the **Republic had adopted the symbol to represent their own role in galactic unification.** A six-spoked form of the symbol was also used by the Republic during the Clone Wars immediately before the rise of the Empire. The symbol was later the basis for the emblem of the Galactic Empire. Then at the end of the Galactic Civil War, the New Republic restored the Old Republic's system government, though with editing of forms to reduce the probability of abuses. The Bendu was reinstated but, due to its similarity to the much-hated Imperial Crest, it was not widely adopted as an official symbol and the Alliance Starbird all but supplanted it.

[image]

> The name "Bendu" may come from George Lucas's original name for the Jedi Knights: the Jedi Bendu. There are several instances wherein the symbol is used. In Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith during the Battle of Coruscant, Anakin's fighter bears the Clone Wars version of the six-spoke symbol and not the eight-spoke symbol. This can be seen when R2 fights the buzz droid.

*Old Republic Logos*

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cool. If eight was significant, do we know what caused the shift from eight to six?

Comment: No idea..but one assumes that the Sith did not have the same beliefs as the Bendu.

Comment: Any idea how this connects to the [First Order symbol](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20150419083934/disney/images/thumb/f/fb/First_Order_logo.png/258px-First_Order_logo.png)? What about the [Red Hot Chili Peppers' logo](http://logonoid.com/images/red-hot-chili-peppers-logo.png)? :P

Comment: As an addendum, the Bendu symbol could easily be seen as appropriate for a galactic republic: All the cultures in the galaxy are equal (the eight identical arcs around the outside), and come together (the spokes) as a single, unified galactic civilisation (the central dot, to which each spoke leads).  If this is the case, then the simplified, six-spoke design could represent the Separatists breaking this galactic unity and leaving the Republic less than "whole", while subtly indicating that they aren't so different from the Sith (or subtly representing the Sith infiltration).

Comment: Furthermore, the Empire's version could be then seen as having two meanings: First, the inverted colour scheme indicates that the Republic has been twisted into its own antithesis.  Second, the way the arcs are no longer simple lines, but have become thinner in the front and wider at the back, indicates that they are no longer equals, but have become subservient to the government.

Comment: Are the Bendu monks part of canon? I think this should be clarified, especially with a character called The Bendu being introduced in *Rebels* this coming season. I can't really tell just by looking at the wiki whether the Bendu monk references are coming from the canon sources or whether it's coming from a combination of sources.

Comment: In case people are curious:  'Bendu' sounds an awful lot like 'Buddha' and a wheel with 8 spokes is a symbol in Buddhism etc:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmachakra

Comment: @Turambar They are not. Just look for the "CANON" or "LEGENDS" banner in the upper right corner of every Wookieepedia article.