# What is the Galactic Senate emblem meant to depict?

Tags: star-wars, symbols

Most of the emblems used throughout *Star Wars* are abstract geometric symbols, often with a radial symmetry pattern. According to the answers to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/141140/83101), they have a spiritual/religious origin.

The [Galactic Senate](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Senate) emblem is rather different from this "standard", it is more elaborate and it's made of several composite shapes:

[image]

These shapes, while still being abstract, seem to depict, or at least being somewhat similar, to stylized real items: a cog, a bird or an aircraft/starship seen from above, or the hilt of a sword.

Is this emblem meant to depict something in particular, or these are just random shapes without any special meaning?

Is the origin of this emblem explained somewhere?

What does it depict?

**My question is mainly related to its graphical aspects.**

Comment: This is, of course, the [Galactic Great Seal of the Senate](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Great_Seal) which represents...erm...the Senate

Comment: Cogs in general in Star Wars relate to a belief in the Force and the Jedi as protectors; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Republic_crest

Comment: @Valorum, Yes, of course it *represents* the Senate :-) But what does it *depicts*? My question is mainly related to its graphical aspects.

Comment: @Sekhemty - It could represent -as a tribute- the compass crafted by Jedi Tes Madurrin who served alongside a succession of Supreme Commanders of the Galactic Republic as a Chief Adviser. Shaving the bone slightly and setting it in a burnished durasteel ring, Madurrin's Force-imbued compass would channel the Force to allow her to find her destination (SW Fanon).

Comment: I did quite a bit of digging on this one cause it caught my interest but so far I've found little to no information on what it represents or its meaning in universe.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer but in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff7ef.jpg) you can see there is actually more definition to the emblem.

Comment: No answer in _The Ultimate Visual Guide_ (2005), _The Complete Visual Dictionary_ (2006), _TPM Expanded Visual Dictionary_ (2012), _Complete Locations_ (2005 or 2016), _Star Wars: Propaganda_, _Ultimate Star Wars_ (2019), Ep I-III Scrapbooks, _The Complete Encyclopedia_, or _Star Wars Chronicles: The Prequels_.

Comment: The emblem shows the Galactic Senate building on Coruscant. It's also an image of the Senate chamber.